# javascript code this is not returning true

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my JavaScript code

```
  function validatenewcat(){
        var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
        if(category==""){
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Category Name", 2000);
            return false;
        }
    else{
        var url="catnamecheck.do?id="+category;
         xmlhttp.open("post", url,true);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=(function (callback){
             return function (){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){      
                 if(xmlhttp.status==200){   
                    var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    obj = JSON.parse(temp);
                  if(obj.catgoryname==category){
                      alert("inside flase");
                     var validate = document.getElementById("validate");
                     validate.innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
                         callback(false); 
                     }
                 if(obj.catgoryname!=category){
                    alert("inside true");
                         callback(true);
                     }
                  }
              }
           }
         })(myCallback);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me this function is not returning true here I'm using ajax to check unique category name from javacode 
This is my call back function

```
  function myCallback(returnedValue) {
        if (returnedValue) {
            alert("entered callback function");
            // true returned. Validation successful. Do whatever you want
            // here in this case.
        }
        else {
            // false returned. Validation failed. Handle the "false" scenario here
            alert("entered callback function");
        }
    }
```

this is my jsp code

```
<form name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp"  method="post" onsubmit="return validatenewcat()">
<table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="validate"></div>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Category Name<span>:</span></th><td><input id="cat"  onblur="return validatenewcat()" type="text" name="category">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Quotations form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="quotations"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Agreement form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="agreement"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Payment form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="payment"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ETI<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="eti"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  style="width: 60px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to return success or failure form callback function this is my edited code

---

This is my javascript code

```
function validatenewcat(){
        var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
        if(category==""){
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Category Name", 2000);
            return false;
                 }
    else{
        var url="catnamecheck.do?id="+category;
         xmlhttp.open("post", url,true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function (){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){      
                 if(xmlhttp.status==200){   
                    var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    obj = JSON.parse(temp);
                   var unique = (obj.catgoryname != category);
                  if(unique ){
                      document.getElementById("newcatform").submit();
                             }
                  else{
                     var validate = document.getElementById("validate");
                     validate.innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
                       }
                  }
              }
           };
           return false;    
        }
```

this is my jsp code

```
<form id="newcatform" name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp"  method="post">
<table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="validate"></div>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Category Name<span>:</span></th><td><input id="cat"  onblur="return validatenewcat()" type="text" name="category">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Quotations form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="quotations"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Agreement form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="agreement"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Payment form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="payment"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ETI<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="eti"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validatenewcat()"  style="width: 60px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

        }
```

Comment: when do you want it to return `true`?

Comment: after the validation is successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code within `onreadystatechange` is called an "[event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)", and will execute only once your POST operation has finished. This is what your `validatenewcat` function is actually doing when you run it:

```
var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
var url = "catnamecheck.do?id=" + category;
xmlhttp.open("post", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (code to be called later)
return false; // <-- Always return false
```

You need to move the code that requires the *TRUE* / *FALSE* result inside the onreadystatechange function, so that it is executed after the HTTP operation has finished:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
            obj = JSON.parse(temp);
            var unique = (obj.catgoryname != category);

            if (unique) {
                // Submit the form to the server
                document.getElementById("newcatform").submit();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your JSP, you can use this function to validate your category before submitting the form:

```
<form id="newcatform" name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" method="post">
...
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validatenewcat()">
</form>
```

Obviously some renaming would also be sensible. For example "validatenewcat()" could become "validateandsend()".

Finally, to avoid timing problems, you should set up your callback function *before* you send the request, so it already exists when the response comes back:

```
xmlhttp.open("post", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // ... callback code here ...
}
xmlhttp.send(null); // <- Move under onreadystatechange callback
```

Comment: // Do something with the result what i can able to do here

Comment: This is where you put the success/failure code. Your original question implied that you required `validatenewcat()` to return true: the code that is expecting true should go in here.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that your "catnamecheck.do" request will not respond right away. The rest of your validatenewcat() function will finish (and will return false), then *later on* the catnamecheck.do response will come back and the code within `onreadystatechange` will be called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `validatenewcat()` is the name of your function, the one you typed in your question.

Comment: I noticed another issue, you are firing xmlhttp.send() before the callback has been declared. You should do this after, to ensure the function exists when the response is returned.

Comment: I've tried the clarify my answer. Do you understand the principles of why your code will never return `true` now? If not, this article might help to give you a working knowledge of how event handlers work: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: validatenewcat() this is my function name this function i'm calling from jsp in form to validate the category name to unique

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the bit of Javascript in your JSP where you call `validatenewcat()`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to make this work with your JSP. You will need to work out how you might validate without submitting the form when using `onblur` (hint: passing a boolean parameter to the function would allow you to check this)

Comment: whts wrong in my updated code how return the true or false value to the validatenewcat form my call back function

Comment: I already explained this in my answer (first paragraph), perhaps I'm not being clear? Javascript event handlers like onreadystatechange are **asynchronous** http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth. In your current code, you are not returning true to validatenewcat(), it has already returned false by the time your callback starts executing. Add another alert("Finished") at the bottom of your function to see what I mean.

Comment: If you followed my instructions then that shouldn't happen. I expect you have something calling validatenewcat() when the page loads...